# Calculate failure rate per city in orders table

Tags: sql

I have an orders table.

```
+----------+--------+---------+
| order_id |  city  | status  |
+----------+--------+---------+
|        1 | NYC    | success |
|        2 | London | failure |
|        3 | Tokyo  | success |
|        4 | NYC    | failure |
|        5 | London | failure |
|        6 | Tokyo  | success |
|        7 | NYC    | success |
|        8 | London | failure |
|        9 | Tokyo  | success |
|       10 | NYC    | failure |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

I want to write a query to list down all cities in ascending order based on its failure rate.

Failure rate for a city = (Failed orders for the city) * 100 / (Total orders for the city)

The output of the query for above table should be:

```
+--------+--------------+
|  city  | failure_rate |
+--------+--------------+
| Tokyo  |            0 |
| NYC    |           50 |
| London |          100 |
+--------+--------------+
```

Now, being a noob, I can only write queries to get count of failed orders grouped by city and total orders grouped by city separately, like following:

```
select city, count(order_id) as failed
from orders
where status='failure'
group by city
order by failed asc;
```

and

```
select city, count(order_id) as total
from orders
group by city
order by total asc;
```

but I am not able to write the query to get the desired result.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select city, 
       sum(case when status='failure' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) as rate
from orders
group by city
order by rate asc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I assumed it would need nested queries. Didn't expect it to be so short.

Comment: @Waltz Or, if you like things short, you can just use `SUM(status='failure')...` (in MySQL anyway)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` to have multiple counts based on condition within same `group by`.

```
select c.*,(failed*100)/total failure_rate
  from (select city
              ,count(*) total
              ,count(order_id) filter (where status='failure') failed
          from orders
        group by city
       ) c
order by failed
```

Comment: @Waltz, just incase you think this is nested query it is not. I just use for readability purpose and same calculation can be done without one level sub query. I just tried to provide another alternative to use `filter` especially. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `avg()` for this purpose.  In generic SQL:

```
select city, 
       avg(case when status = 'failure' then 1.0 else 0 end) as fail_rate
from orders
group by city
order by fail_rate asc;
```

The calculation can also be simplified depending on the database.  In MySQL, for instance:

```
       avg( status = 'failure' ) as fail_rate
```

In Postres/Redshift:

```
       avg( (status = 'failure')::int ) as fail_rate
```